# XFCE or pure X11 commands, toggle compositing immediately without restarting X

Tags: command-line, shell-script, xorg, xfce, composite

How can i disable compositing via the command line? I need to disable temporarily for some games, like Nexuiz, for use in a wrapper script to toggle compositing status.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -t bool -s false
```

`true` to activate it again.

Comment: This helped me get my Raspberry Pi 4 running XFCE headless to work correctly. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just make a keyboard shortcut for this:

```
xfconf-query --channel=xfwm4 --property=/general/use_compositing --type=bool --toggle
```

Toggle compositing at the tip of your finger =)
P.S: Sorry for necroposting.