# Disabling an Xorg server's extension at runtime (for new clients)?

Tags: x11, xorg, gui, altlinux

I have an old Xorg server whose ["Render" extension seems to be buggy (if enabled, most of the fonts are invisible, unless hovering over them -- after upgrading the packages with X clients and libraries)](https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29956).

So, the problem is solved for new instances of the Xorg server by adding to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Extensions"
    Option      "RENDER" "Disable"
EndSection
```

But what if I want to continue an X session, but make new clients not use the extension? (Of course, logically, [old clients can't be made not to use it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4288/4319); but what about new ones?) Some options are:

1. Can I turn one of the server's extension off on the fly, while the server is running?
2. Can I tell the clients not to use it (e.g., those written with a specific toolkit)?
3. IS there an "X proxy" which could be used for my goal: the proxy could simply not advertise that it has a "Render" extension, or translate the requests that involve it, and forward everything to the "physical" X server, and my new clients would then connect to the proxy's DISPLAY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For occational use you could plug [xtrace](http://xtrace.alioth.debian.org/) between your client and your server and make the client not see any extensions by using xtrace's -e switch:

> ```
>   -e | --denyextensions
>          Modify all server replies to say there are no extensions
>          available.  (As xtrace does supports only a small number of
>          extensions anyway and calls all extended requests "unknown"
>          and  all replies to such requests "unexpected").
> ```

You will not see any extensions so it is of no help to "disable"/hide a single extension. For this case you could try to modify the source (I guess parse.c:replyQueryExtension() is the place).

Second catch is that using xtrace will probably slow down your client.